# STM32 F407 Discovery Joystick Thrustmaster T-Flight Hotas X

Tags: usb, microcontroller, stm32

I am trying to use the Thrustmaster T-Flight Hotas X joystick with my STM32 f407 Discovery board. As you know, the joystick has a USB connection, but actually I do not know how it transmits data and I do not know what kind of protocol it uses...do you have any advice?

Is there a way to connect the joystick to the board?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the USB OTG port in host mode to connect your joystick.

The joystick will use USB HID protocol - this is documented in detail at usb.org. Short version: The device tells you in its "report descriptor" how the data is formatted. The data itself is transmitted via interrupt endpoint.

Unfortunately, the software side is non-trivial, as you need host mode on the MCU. Parsing the report descriptor is not required if you only ever use the same joystick model - which can be identified using the VID:PID in the device descriptor.

There should be an appnote with some example code for USB host mode on the STM website, but in order to support your joystick you probably have to make some modifications - which are rather difficult for beginners.